# Detect repeat and new customers

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to figure how to write a LINQ query that will return two lists of customers who have checked in for the first time and who didn't check in on a given date

```
Cusomters
- Name (nvarchar)
- CheckInDate (datetime)
```

I can write two separate queries, but is it possible to just use a single query?

Comment: Show the code for your two queries, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return 1 list of 2 kinds of customer as you want:

```
var result = Customers.GroupBy(x=>x.Name)
                      .Where(g=>g.Count()==1 || !g.Any(x=>x.CheckInDate == yourDate))
                      .SelectMany(x=>x);
```

If you want 2 lists, I think this would work:

```
var result = Customers.GroupBy(x=> Customers.Count(a=>a.Name == x.Name) == 1 ? 1 : 2)
                      .Select(g=> g.Key == 1 ? g.ToList() : g.Where(x=>!g.Where(a=>a.CheckInDate == yourDate)
                                                                         .Any(a=>a.Name == x.Name)).ToList());
//To get the customers who have first checked in
var firstCheckedIn = result[0];
//To get the customers who didn't check in on a given date
var notCheckedIn = result[1]

//or

var result = Customers.GroupBy(x=> {
                                    var c = Customers.Where(a=>a.Name == x.Name);
                                    return c.Count() == 1 ? 1 :
                                           !c.Any(a=>a.CheckInDate == yourDate) ? 2 : 3;
                                   })                                        
                      .Select(g=> g.ToList()).ToList();
```